# How to get username in PHP using Active Directory without username and password

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

How to determine and store to variable a user name which is connected with Active Directory in PHP?

I read that it's easy to do using Windows authentication on IIS with AUTH_USER variable, but unfortunately the website will be on a Linux server or on XAMPP

And I need to do it without modules, such as mod_auth_kerb and mod_ntlm.

I was thinking of doing this through an LDAP request. Ask for username and password and make ldap_bind or ldap_connect. If the username and password are correct, then our LDAP server responds and we put username in the variable

But I don't like the idea of asking for a user password, because it will be transmitted in plain text?
In our AD, TLS and SSL are not configured, and there is no access to configure them.

Are there any other options?

Comment: Yes you can fairly easily use LDAP for this, but you will obviously require the `mod_ldap` module. You can call `ldap_connect()` and then `ldap_bind()` with the user DN and password and it will return true/false. The password will be transmitted in plain text if you don't have SSL/TLS configured... and egad, why don't you have SSL/TLS configured?

Comment: Get TLS configured. Period.

Comment: I can't configure TLS because it's not my domain.
So seems  there are no other ways to get the username?